# Why my attribute disappear?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a class like this:

```
global class CustomerStudyFeilds {
public String FeildName{ get; set; }
public String ChooseType{ get; set; }
public double Length{ get; set; }
public boolean IfRequired{ get; set; }
}
```

And a component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.feildlists}" var="feild">                    
     <br />
     <p>{!feild.FeildName}</p>
</aura:iteration>
```

And the Apex Controller:**(in the controller I can get back the FeildName and so on)**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<CustomerStudyFeilds> getAllFeilds(Study__c study) {
    String sojname = study.Name + '__c';
    List<CustomerStudyFeilds> wulala = MetadataServiceExamples.readCustomObject(sojname);
    system.debug('=========================================================');
    system.debug(wulala.get(0));
    system.debug(wulala.get(0).FeildName); //**here I can get the right name of the feild.**

    return wulala;
}
```

controller.js:**(but when it comes to here feildlists[0] don't have the attribute how Can I sovle it?)**

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("init method");
    var action = component.get("c.getAllFeilds");
    action.setParams({
        "study": component.get("v.study")
    });
    // Add callback behavior for when response is received
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.feildlists", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log(component.get("v.feildlists")[0].FeildName);//**but here I got nothing!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
        }
    });

    // Send action off to be executed
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

Can you explain me why?
because I can not get the right value in the controller so I can not display it !It is very kind of you ! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response object's members should contain **@AuraEnabled** annotation, only then it will be available in the client side controller.

So add the **@AuraEnabled** to the CustomerStudyFeilds's class members.

```
public class CustomerStudyFeilds {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String FeildName{ get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String ChooseType{ get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public double Length{ get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public boolean IfRequired{ get; set; }
}
```